# Newtonsoft JSON.Net SelectToken Issue

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

I have the following query and the sample JSON. 
I try it on "http://jsonpath.com/" it works as expected.
If I try it in VisualStudio it returns no results.

```
$.Items.Services[?(@.Name ==  'Another Service')].Url
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{
"Items": {
    "Resource": {
        "Id": "12345"
    },
    "Services": {
        "service1": {
            "Name": "My First Service",
            "Type": "WS",
            "Url": "https://server1/service1"
        },
        "service2": {
            "Name": "Another Service",
            "Type": "WS",
            "Url": "https://server2/service2"
        }
    }
}   
}
```

And the sample code:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"d:\temp\sample.json"));
var matches = obj.SelectTokens("$.Items.Services[?(@.Name ==  'Another Service')].Url");
if(matches != null)
{
    foreach(var item in matches)
    {
       item.Replace(replacement); // this never gets executed
    }
 }
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you made a typo and are calling the correct method `.SelectToken` instead of `.SelectTokens` ?

Comment: No. I was calling the plural. Is that not what it's expected to do?

Comment: Ah, I realized there is also the plural method in the lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var matches = obj.SelectTokens("$.Items.Services[?(@..Name == 'Another Service')]..Url");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! 
I just don't know why. but who cares as long as it's returning results.

Comment: Adding `..` in front of the square bracket and keeping the rest same also works