# Json.NET JSONPath query not returning expected results

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I'm using Newtonsoft's Json.Net to select nodes from the following json:

```
{  
   "projects":[  
      {  
         "name":"Project 1",
         "client":{  
            "code":"ABC",
            "name":"Client 1"
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"Project 2",
         "client":{  
            "code":"DEF",
            "name":"Client 2"
         }
      },
      {  
         "name":"Project 3",
         "client":{  
            "code":"GHI",
            "name":"Client 3"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The following c# snippet

```
//json is a JObject representation of the json listed above
var clients =  json.SelectTokens("$.projects[*].client");
```

Yields:

```
[  
   {  
      "code":"ABC",
      "name":"Client 1"
   },
   {  
      "code":"DEF",
      "name":"Client 2"
   },
   {  
      "code":"GHI",
      "name":"Client 3"
   }
]
```

Which is cool, now, what I'd like to do is filter by client code, I would think that

```
$.projects[*].client[?(@.code == 'DEF')]
```

would work, but I obviously don't understand the syntax well enough. This returns an empty list:

```
 var test1 =  json.SelectTokens("$.projects[*].client[?(@.code == 'DEF')]").ToList();
```

And the single token selector returns a null:

```
  var test2 =  json.SelectToken("$.projects[*].client[?(@.code == 'DEF')]");
```

I tried a few different configurations on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ and it seems my query syntax is indeed broken.

Using Flow Communications' JSONPath 0.3.4 implementation (on the above link) I can get the client  using

```
$..[?(@.code == 'DEF')]
```

however, this syntax does not seem valid for Json.Net (nor the Goessner implementation on the same page).

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could try swapping to jayway's implementation here which will work. https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Json.NET's [JSONPath parser](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/JPath.cs) allows the filter (script) expression `[?( )]` to query for nested properties inside child objects of the candidate array item(s).  Thus

```
var test = json.SelectTokens(@"$.projects[?(@.client.code == 'DEF')].client");
```

returns, as desired,

```
[
  {
    "code": "DEF",
    "name": "Client 2"
  }
]
```

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dEWMgK).

Upon experimentation it seems none of the JSONPath implementations at [jsonpath.curiousconcept.com](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) support this syntax, however it works correctly at [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/) which uses https://github.com/ashphy/jsonpath-online-evaluator.  The [JSONPath proposal](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) simply states that `()` is a **script expression, using the underlying script engine** which clearly leaves some room for interpretation as to whether and how this "should" work.

The filters used in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45297883/3744182) apparently do not work with Json.NET because, as of version 10.0.3, it only officially supports applying filters to array items and not directly to objects -- see [Issue #1256: JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256) for a discussion.  (Though sometimes cunning workarounds can be found, for instance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453636/3744182).)  Using nested properties inside filters, however, seems to be intended to work (and does work).

Comment: It seems that the online implementations all behave differently. It works perfectly in my solution, **thank you**. Just so I understand the logic, the filter is supposed to be applied to arrays?  - In this example you filter on project […] because it is an array but not in client {…} because it is a single object (and therefore cannot be filtered)?

Comment: @Jaco - *The filter is supposed to be applied to arrays?*  Yes.  It seems Json.NET does not officially support filtering objects inside objects as of 10.0.3.  See [Issue #1256: JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256).  Though sometimes cunning workarounds can be found, for instance in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453636/3744182).