# JsonPath SelectToken not working for recursive structure

Tags: json.net, jsonpath, recursive-descent

I have the following JSON on which I want to get specific values using SelectToken -

```
{
  "Result": {
    "Id": "knownvalue0",
    "Name": "Level0",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Name": "Level1",
        "Id": "knownvalue1",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Name": "Level2",
            "Id": "knownvalue2",
            "Children": [
              {
                "Id": "knownvalue3",
                "Name": "Level3",
                "Children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The structure is recursive and I do not know the depth at runtime. However I do know the Ids and want to verify that the names are correct. So I use a JsonPath like this  - `Result..[?(@Id=='knownvalue')].Name in jtoken.parse(response).selecttoken(jsonpath)` method. A problem is occurring when I am using this jsonpath on knownvalue1 or knownvalue2 i.e -

```
Result..[?(@Id=='knownvalue1')].Name
```

I am getting exception - Path is returning multiple tokens. Why is the selecttoken returning multiple tokens even though there is only 1 name with Id  = 'knownvalue1'?? The Level2 and Level3 nodes are children, they should not be returned.

Comment: `"Result..Children[?(@Id=='knownvalue1')].Name"` works as expected, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/RvN0Zy.  Not sure what's wrong with your query though.

Comment: Alternatively, on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/, both `Result..[?(@Id=='knownvalue1')].Name` and `Result..Children[?(@Id=='knownvalue1')].Name` generate an error -- but `Result..[?(@.Id=='knownvalue1')].Name` (and `Result..Children[?(@.Id=='knownvalue1')].Name`) work as expected when using *Flow Communications JSONPath 0.4.0* -- but none work using Goessner.

Comment: `Result..*[?(@Id=='knownvalue1')].Name` also works if you don't want to hardcode the name `Children`.  Apparently the recursive descent operator has to terminate in some sort of property name for the subsequent array indexer to behave as expected.

Comment: Is that a sufficient answer?

Comment: @dbc - yeah Result..Children worked yesterday as well. Only problem is that the root node itself isn't inside 'Children', so have to write separate one for that. I will try Result..*[...] and get back on this, thank you.

Comment: `SelectToken()` isn't guaranteed to work for objects inside objects -- only objects inside arrays.  See: [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256#issuecomment-289134144): *I'm not sure about this. Nothing in the JSONPath says that filters should apply to objects.*.  Sometimes workarounds can be found, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298348/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453636/3744182).