# Json path to find all objects having the particular property

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

It seems that it is a trivial task for the "JSON path" language but I cannot solve it properly.
To test my attempts I use https://jsonpath.com/ and Newtonsoft.NET library.

I have a very simple JSON:

```
{"config":{"id":"id1","key":"k1"},"external":{"config":{"key":"k2"}}}
```

And I want to find all "config" objects that have the property "id" presented.
I thoght the query `$..config[?(@.id)]` should work but it doesn't.

The query `$..[?(@.id)]` works for my example but in the general case, it's obviously not exactly what I want.

Also, the first query works for a little bit another JSON:

```
{"config":[{"id":"id1","key":"k1"}],"external":{"config":[{"key":"k2"}]}}
```

but, again, that's not strictly what I need.

Could you, please, show me the error in my reasoning and the correct JSON path query exactly matching my needs?

Comment: Your two examples are the same. Did you mean to post a different payload the second time?

Comment: Nevermind. I see the array in the second one.

Comment: Your queries look valid, but be aware that JSON Path isn't codified yet. There's a spec effort, but it's still in progress.

Comment: https://jsonpath.com/  uses [JSONPath Plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus). Each implementation differs slightly in terms of the proposed [spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html) .

Comment: Currently [Jayway JSONpath (Java DSL)](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) supports your query `$..config[?(@.id)]`.  Try it here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/. Unfortunately for [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) you can use the query only if config is an array

Comment: Akshay G, why does that work that way in Newtonsoft? Is it kind of a bug or the expected behaviour? Should I create a bug in their github?

Comment: It's not a bug in Newtonsoft because even JSONPath-plus seems to lack the same feature which is fully compliant with the original jsonpath spec.  Use the combination of [JSON Path and LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm) instead.

Comment: `SelectToken()` isn't guaranteed to work for objects inside objects -- only objects inside arrays.  See: [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256#issuecomment-289134144): *I'm not sure about this. Nothing in the JSONPath says that filters should apply to objects.*  Sometimes workarounds can be found, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45298348/3744182) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453636/3744182).